# Help me to optimize hard logic on SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, sql-optimization

First I'll try (with my bad English) to explain what I've got and what I need to have

I have got the list of Events by TimeLine.

Event is some discrete signal 1/0 that happens in some time and got some duration.

my event list is looking like

```
Rectime - start event time
Col - event name
ChangedDate - end event time
InitalValue - event message
Value - event state 1/0
```

And those events can call some Complex event if there are ***A1 event is 1 A2 is 0 or A5 is 1 in the same time*** -- **Just for example**

my complex events (incidents) structure is :

```
[ID] - just ID
[Name] - just Name 
[SQL] - here is list of event names with logics alike ***(A1 AND NOT A2) OR A5***
[Message] - event message
```

I need do not miss any possible change so I when some event is happens I'm looking for complex events it could change , but to know if that changed complex events I need to know about other depends of this complex event, so next step is getting all the dependent events and their states 1/0. Here is my try :

```
With DependencedIncidents AS -- Get all dependenced Incidents from this Event
(
    SELECT INC.[RecTime],INC.[SQL] AS [str] FROM
    (
        SELECT A.[RecTime] As [RecTime],X.[SQL] As [SQL] FROM [EventView] AS A 
        CROSS JOIN [Incident] AS X
            WHERE
                patindex('%' + A.[Col] + '%', X.[SQL]) > 0
    ) AS INC
)
, DependencedEvents AS -- Split SQL string to get dependeced Events for each dependeced Incident
(
    select distinct word AS [Event] , [RecTime]
    from
    (
        select v.number, t.[RecTime] As [RecTime],
            substring(t.str+')',
                      v.number+1,
                      patindex('%[() ]%',
                               substring(t.str+')',
                                         v.number+1,
                                         1000))-1) word
        from DependencedIncidents AS t
        inner join master..spt_values v on v.type='P'
          and v.number < len(t.str)
          and (v.number=0 or substring(t.str,v.number,1) like '[() ]')
    ) x
    where word not in ('','OR','AND')
)
, EventStates AS -- Dependeced events with their states 1/0
(
    Select D.[RecTime], D.[Event], X.[Value]
    From [DependencedEvents] AS D
    LEFT JOIN [EventView] AS X 
        ON X.Col = D.[Event]
        AND D.[Rectime] >= X.[Rectime]
        AND D.[Rectime] <= X.[ChangedDate]
)

select * from EventStates
order by [RecTime]
```

And it works very very slow , I need a serious optimization if that possible.

The slowest ( 95% of time ) part is

```
LEFT JOIN [EventView] AS X 
    ON X.Col = D.[Event]
    AND D.[Rectime] BETWEEN X.[Rectime] AND  X.[ChangedDate]
```

maybe I'm doing something wrong here...

I just want to check Value of D.[Event] from EventView in this time D.[Rectime]...

eventview added by comments requests :

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[EventView] AS
            (SELECT RecTime, ChangedDate, ( 'Alarm' + CAST(ID as nvarchar(MAX)) ) AS Col, InitialValue, Value FROM [dbo].[Changes]
                WHERE InitialValue <> '')
            UNION ALL
            SELECT RecTime, ChangedDate, Col, InitialValue, Value FROM [dbo].[XDeltaIntervals]
            UNION ALL
            SELECT RecTime, ChangedDate, Col, InitialValue, Value FROM [dbo].[ActvXDeltaIntervals]
```

Comment: Is `EventView` a view or a table?

Comment: Could please you add its definition to your question?

Comment: yes ... but structure at all is very complex , added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should be about the same:

```
SELECT
  ev.Rectime,
  ev.Event,
  ev2.Value
FROM EventView AS ev
  INNER JOIN Incident i
    ON PATINDEX('%' + ev.Col + '%', i.SQL) > 0
  LEFT JOIN EventView ev2
    ON ev.Col = ev2.Col AND ev.Rectime BETWEEN ev2.Rectime AND ev2.ChangedDate
```

The thing is, you are finding your complex events using event names, then you are extracting those very names from the complex events found, and finally you are using the extracted names in the last CTE to compare against themselves. So, it seemed to me that the extracting part was completely unnecessary.

And without it the resulting query turned out to be quite simple (in appearance at least).

Comment: Sad but query executing still being about 7 minutes on test data - that is very slow.

Comment: But this is 10-20% faster then my query.

Comment: and... extracting part is necessary.

Comment: @Bjorky: It's perfectly fine to be hesitant in accepting an answer. You needn't worry too much about that. You question is valid. The unclear parts, if they are present, will be asked about. So, if you are still unsure about my answer, please feel free to withdraw your accept. :) I'm only trying to be helpful, and if you accept my answer in doubts, then I can't be sure whether I have actually helped you. Now, please tell me, why you think you need to perform that join, whether inner or left. If the join is unnecessary, it can happen that you will see it yourself while trying to justify it. :)

Comment: @Andriy M I made to much workarounds and I've got a new question about my situation , but absolutely new one for sure. This question is solved, maybe mostly by myself but with your help and now it works fine, so let's go to next question )

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the most basic concepts of relational data storage is to

- store the data in a normalized way and
- use the relational database to store the data, but do not parse/process it etc. Use the application layer to do that.

That should be the first thing you do and then you may move to the next level of optimizing the queries, joins, making indices etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think the slowest part is originating from EventView definiton:

```
SELECT ... ( 'Alarm' + CAST(ID as nvarchar(MAX)) ) AS Col, ...
```

Joining with such calculated field causes nasty performance hit.

Can't you:

- record (Col=)Alarm+ID directly to Changes table or
- update Alarm+ID by trigger or
- use indexed view for calculating Alarm+ID or
- use temporary table for storing Alarm+ID or at least
- not use nvarchar(MAX), but something like nvarchar(10) (if this changes query plan)

?

Comment: Thank you but that is not slowest part, slowest part was I making JOIN by RecTime field - it's awesome slow process.